# VB.NET (2013) - Check string against huge file

Tags: vb.net, filesize

I have a text file that is 125Mb in size, it contains 2.2 million records.  I have another text file which doesn't match the original but I need to find out where it differs.  Normally, with a smaller file I would read each line and process it in some way, or read the whole file into a string and do likewise, however the two files are too big for that and so I would like to create something to achieve my goal.  Here's what I currently have.. excuse the mess of it.

```
    Private Sub refUpdateBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles refUpdateBtn.Click
    Dim refOrig As String = refOriginalText.Text 'Original Reference File
    Dim refLatest As String = refLatestText.Text 'Latest Reference
    Dim srOriginal As StreamReader = New StreamReader(refOrig) 'start stream of original file
    Dim srLatest As StreamReader = New StreamReader(refLatest) 'start stream of latest file

    Dim recOrig, recLatest, baseDIR, parentDIR, recOutFile As String

    baseDIR = vb.Left(refOrig, InStrRev(refOrig, ".ref") - 1) 'find parent folder
    parentDIR = Path.GetDirectoryName(baseDIR) & "\"
    recOutFile = parentDIR & "Updated.ref"

    Me.Text = "Processing Reference File..." 'update the application
    Update()

    If Not File.Exists(recOutFile) Then
        FileOpen(55, recOutFile, OpenMode.Append)
        FileClose(55)
    End If

    Dim x As Integer = 0

    Do While srLatest.Peek() > -1
        Application.DoEvents()
        recLatest = srLatest.ReadLine
        recOrig = srOriginal.ReadLine ' check the original reference file

        Do
            If Not recLatest.Equals(recOrig) Then
                recOrig = srOriginal.ReadLine
            Else
                FileOpen(55, recOutFile, OpenMode.Append)
                Print(55, recLatest & Environment.NewLine)
                FileClose(55)
                x += 1
                count.Text = "Record No: " & x
                count.Refresh()
                srOriginal.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                GoTo 1
            End If
        Loop
    1:
    Loop
    srLatest.Close()
    srOriginal.Close()
    FileClose(55)

End Sub
```

It's got poor programming and scary loops, but that's because I'm not a professional coder, just a guy trying to make his life easier.

Currently, this uses a form to insert the original file and the latest file and outputs each line that matches into a new file.  This is less than perfect, but I don't know how to cope with the large file sizes as ***streamreader.readtoend*** crashes the program.  I also don't need the output to be a copy of the latest input, but I don't know how to only output the records it doesn't find.  Here's a sample of the records each file has:

```
doc:ARCHIVE.346CCBD3B06711E0B40E00163505A2EF
doc:ARCHIVE.346CE683B29811E0A06200163505A2EF
doc:ARCHIVE.346CEB15A91711E09E8900163505A2EF
doc:ARCHIVE.346CEC6AAA6411E0BEBB00163505A2EF
```

The program I have currently works... to a fashion, however I know there are better ways of doing it and I'm sure much better ways of using the CPU and memory, but I don't know this level of programming.  All I would like is for you to take a look and offer your best answers to all or some of the code.  Tell me what you think will make it better, what will help with one line, or all of it.  I have no time limit on this because the code works, albeit slowly, I would just like someone to tell me where my code could be better and what I could do to get round the huge file sizes.

Comment: If you computer crashes while trying to read two 125mb files them I presume you dont have much free ram. It depends on how much the file is likely to have changed. Are you looking to find out what records have been deleted? Or more - like record insertions or changes to a record? Searching for all of these things can make the code quite complex and more memory hungry. How much FREE RAM do you have?

Comment: David, thanks for your reply.  In answer to your questions: I am using a Hyper-V machine to run this code on.  I suppose technically there is 12Gb of RAM on the host PC, however the hyper-v chooses how much it needs, but let's say 8Gb.  What I would like to see is the original file recreated with only the records that don't exist in the latest file.  I've made a few minor changes to the code already as the process would hang in a loop if the original file didn't have a record that the latest file did have.  Now it outputs that record to an error file.

Comment: OK. Just a thought, are you compiling the program to a 32-bit exe or a 64bit one. I had a similar problem with a program I wrote. Because I was compiling to 32bit, it was unable to access all the extra memory and was crashing.

Comment: Thanks again David for your question.  Honestly I have no idea about the compiling process.  The server is 64Bit, but I doubt that's what you mean.  I selected the 'Build solution' from the 'Build' menu, but I'm not aware of using different O/S architecture to compile a program.

Comment: OK try this. In the Solution Explorer, right click on your project and click properties. This should open a new tab in the main window. On the left had side you should be able to select Compile. In the new options that appear there should be one that says 'Target CPU'. Check that this option is set to x64. Then rebuild your project and run it to see if that helps

Comment: David.  Thank you for your efforts.  I think I may have hit an issue on the system I am currently running.  The Hyper-V machine I am running states clearly that the O/S and CPU are x64, however when trying to compile the application, I get an 'MSBuild' error which states the x64 architecture is unavailable on this system.  This would suggest that VS2013 cannot see it's on a Hyper-V machine and believes it to be otherwise.  With this in mind I will place VS directly on my PC and try again. I may be some time before letting you know how things went.

Comment: I had a similar problem using vmware.  In the bios on the pc running hyper-v do you have virtualization enabled? When I enabled it on my pc,  I could run vmware machines in 64bit mode

Answer (score 0):

Your code is slow because it is doing *a lot* of file IO. You're on the right track by reading one line at a time, but this can be improved.

Firstly, I've created some test files based off the data that you provided. Those files contain three million lines and are about 130 MB in size (2.2 million records was less than 100 MB so I've increased the number of lines to get to the file size that you state).

Reading the entire file into a single string uses up about 600 MB of memory. Do this with two files (which I assume you were doing) and you have over 1GB of memory used, which may have been causing the crash (you don't say what error was shown, if any, when the crash occurred, so I can only assume that it was an `OutOfMemoryException`).

Here's a few tips before I go through your code:

### Use `Using` Blocks

This won't help with performance, but it does make your code cleaner and easier to read.

Whenever you're dealing with a file (or anything that implements the [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface), it's always a good idea to use a [Using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx). This will automatically dispose of the file (which closes the file), even if an error happens.

### Don't use FileOpen

The [`FileOpen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.fileopen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is outdated (and even stated as being slow in its documentation). There are better alternatives that you are already (almost) using: [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (the cousin of [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Opening and closing a file two million times (like you are doing inside your loop) won't be fast. This can be improved by opening the file once outside the loop.

### `DoEvents()` is evil!

`DoEvents` is a legacy method from back in the VB6 days, and it's something that you really want to avoid, especially when you're calling it two million times in a loop!

The alternative is to perform all of your file processing on a separate thread so that your UI is still responsive.

Using a separate thread here is probably overkill, and there are a number of intricacies that you need to be aware of, so I have not used a separate thread in the code below.

---

So let's look at each part of your code and see what we can improve.

#### Creating the output file

You're *almost* right here, but you're doing some things that you don't need to do. `GetDirectoryName` works with file names, so there's no need to remove the extension from the original file name first. You can also use the `Path.Combine` method to combine a directory and file name.

```
recOutFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(refOrig), "Updated.ref")
```

#### Reading the files

Since you're looping through each line in the "latest" file and finding a match in the "original" file, you can continue to read one line at a time from the "latest" file.
But instead of reading a line at a time from the "original" file, then seeking back to the start when you find a match, you will be better off reading all of those lines into memory.

Now, instead of reading the *entire* file into memory (which took up 600 MB as I mentioned earlier), you can read each line of the file into an array. This will use up less memory, and is quite easy to do thanks to the `File` class.

```
originalLines = File.ReadAllLines(refOrig)
```

This reads all of the lines from the file and returns a `String` array. Searching through this array for matches will be slow, so instead of reading into an array, we can read into a `HashSet(Of String)`. This will use up a bit more memory, but it will be much faster to seach through.

```
originalLines = New HashSet(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines(refOrig))
```

#### Searching for matches

Since we now have all of the lines from the "original" line in an array or `HashSet`, searching for a line is very easy.

```
originalLines.Contains(recLatest)
```

### Putting it all together

So let's put all of this together:

```
Private Sub refUpdateBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim refOrig As String
    Dim refLatest As String
    Dim recOutFile As String
    Dim originalLines As HashSet(Of String)


    refOrig = refOriginalText.Text 'Original Reference File
    refLatest = refLatestText.Text 'Latest Reference

    recOutFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(refOrig), "Updated.ref")

    Me.Text = "Processing Reference File..." 'update the application
    Update()

    originalLines = New HashSet(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines(refOrig))

    Using latest As New StreamReader(refLatest),
          updated As New StreamWriter(recOutFile, True)

        Do
            Dim line As String


            line = latest.ReadLine()

            ' ReadLine returns Nothing when it reaches the end of the file.
            If line Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            If originalLines.Contains(line) Then
                updated.WriteLine(line)
            End If
        Loop
    End Using
End Sub
```

This uses around 400 MB of memory and takes about 4 seconds to run.

Comment: thirdwaffle has offered insight and experience into my programming knowledge and given me reasons for each change with a fine example of how to complete the process in less than 1% of the time it actually took me.  I made one change to your program Mr. Waffle to remove the section of the hashset if it existed: `originalLines.Remove(line)` and output the line to a new file if it didn't exist. `Else : output.WriteLine(line)`
This means I ended up with a smaller file with all the unique references in, knowing that every line was checked.  Thanks for your time & effort in answering my question.